# Is the following binary quadratic integer programming NP-Hard？

Tags: computability, np-complete, np-hard, quadratic-programming

I'am trying to prove the following binary quadratic integer programming problem NP hard.

$$
\min \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^m(u_i-\bar u)^2}{m}\text{ ,   where }u=Q x,Q\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}\\
s.t. \begin{cases}
Ax\leq b, \ A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n},b\in\mathbb{R}^m
\\Cx=d, \ C\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n},d\in\mathbb{R}^m\\
\forall i: x_{i}\in\{0,1\}\end{cases}
$$

- x is a n-dimensional **programming variable**.
- u is a m-dimensional vector, and $\bar u = \frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^mu_i}{m}$.
- A, C, Q are **constant** coefficient **matrices**.
- b, d are **constant** coefficient **vectors**.

I guess it could be reduced into the knapsack problem. But because of the complexity of the target function, I haven't figured out how to relate it to the knapsack problem.

Comment: Sums are ugly.  Just write $$\frac1m \| {\bf u} - {\bar u} {\bf 1}_m \|_2^2 = \frac1m \left\| \left( {\bf I}_m -\frac1m {\bf 1}_m  {\bf 1}_m^\top \right) {\bf u}  \right\|_2^2$$ and note that ${\bf I}_m -\frac1m {\bf 1}_m  {\bf 1}_m^\top$ is a projection matrix

Comment: Your matrices and vectors should be over $\Bbb Q$

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: this horrible notation hides the fact that the cost function is a variance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is NP-hard. Well, to be precise, currently, it is not specified what happens when there is no $x$ that satisfies all constraints. Determining whether a valid solution for $x$ exists is NP-hard, as the integer linear program feasiblity is a special case of this problem. But I think you're more interested in the optimization part.

So, suppose $A,B,c,d$ are chosen such that there always is a solution for $x$ that satisfies the constraints. Then the problem is still NP-hard. Let $\mathsf{IS'}$ be the problem of finding a maximum independent set in graphs where there exists an independent set of size at least half the number of nodes. For every graph $G$ with $n$ vertices, we can create a graph $G'$ that is a valid input for $\mathsf{IS'}$ by adding $n$ isolated vertices to $G$. With this observation, it is easy to show $\mathsf{IS'}$ is NP-hard via a reduction from the ordinary independent set problem.

We can now encode $\mathsf{IS'}$ as an instance of this optimization program, which shows the problem is NP-hard. For simplicity, I'm assuming $A$ may have more rows than $Q$. We can obtain these extra rows by padding $x$ with extra values of which we can fix the sum using $C$.

Given a graph $G$ of $n$ vertices, let $x$ be a vector where the indices $i$ correspond to vertices $v_i$ in $G$.

For each edge $(v_i,v_j)$ in $G$, add the constraint $x_i+x_j\leq 1$. Also, add the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \geq n/2$. Let $Q$ be the identity matrix, $C$ and $d$ can be set to $0$. Note that the construction of $\mathsf{IS}'$ guarantees there exists an $x$ that satisfies these constraints.

Due to the edge constraint, the set of vertices $v_i$ where $x_i=1$ is an independent set in $G$. Due to the second constraint, at least half of the entries of $x$ are set to $1$. The objective function calculates the variance of $Qx= x$, which is strictly decreasing in the number of $1$-entries under the condition that at least half of the entries are $1$. So, a minimum objective function for $x$ corresponds to maximum independent set in $G$.

Comment: I kind of get a rough understanding of your proof. Since I have not studied the computational complexity theory, I have the following problems about your proof:

- I don't understand how constraint  $x_i+x_j\leq 1$ affects the corresponding edge $<v_i,v_j>$ in graph G. Does it mean that there is at most one edge between two vertices?

Comment: 2. Based on your proof, may I take your statement to mean that you constructed a special instance of my programming problem (I see that you set special conditions for A, C, Q, d) and then connected this special case to an NP-hard problem: reducing this instance to the MIS problem. I wonder if the conclusion is still tenable for A, C, Q and d in other cases.  I mean I want to know how to compare the hadness between the instance and the original problem.

Comment: 3. Finally, I have seen some notes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction, below the example header) showing that proving problem P is NP-hard requires reducing an NP-hard problem (let's call it problem Q) to problem P, which illustrate the difficulty of solving P is greater than or equal to the NP-hard problem Q. Thus proving that the problem P is NP-hard. From your proof process, I seem to see that the problem instance is reduced to MIS problem. I am a little confused.

Comment: 1. The entries of $x$ with value 1 correspond to the vertices in a potentially independent set. So, $x_i+x_j\leq 1$ means we can select at most one of $v_i,v_j$ for the set. We need to have this constraint for every edge to ensure no pair of vertices in the independent set have an edge in $G$. 2. If $A'$ is a more specific problem of $A$, then showing $A'$ is NP-hard implies $A$ is NP-hard. This is also how reductions generally work: the map in a reduction from problem $A$ to $B$ is usually not surjective.

Comment: 3. I'm not sure what you're referring to, the page you link has no example header. Indeed, we need to reduce Q to P. In the proof, I first claim we can reduce IS' from IS (i.e. IS reduces to IS') and then reduce IS' to the problem in question.